# Can not Install apk from assets directory

Tags: android

i want to install .apk from assets directory.For installing first i copy .apk file from assets directory to internal storage or to sdCard then try to install it but because of unknown app  install permission application didn't install

```
val assetManager: AssetManager = assets
        try {
            var file = File(path)
            file.mkdir()

            var outputFile = File(path, "testing_app.apk")

            if (outputFile.exists()) {
                outputFile.delete()
            }
            var inputStream: InputStream = assetManager.open("testing_app.apk")
            var outputStream: OutputStream

            outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            var byteArray = ByteArray(1024)

            while (true) {
                val read: Int = inputStream.read(byteArray)
                if (read < 0) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(byteArray, 0, read)

            }

            inputStream.close()

            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()

            var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

            intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(File("${path}/testing_app.apk")),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
            )

            startActivity(intent)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("AppError", e.message)

        }
```

Comment: you need to allow unkown source application instal permission from the setting

Answer (score 0):

With the current API, you have to indicate this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- required for installing other packages on Android O -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

... and the user also needs to enable "install from unknown sources", in the settings.